# Are vendor tags ever appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today during edit reviews that someone was adding the [Telerik tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/telerik/info) to many posts.  If you read the tag description, the tag appears to be set up as a 'vendor tag' - a tag representing a company rather than a product or service:

> Telerik is a vendor of development, team productivity, and automated testing tools, as well as UI components and content management solutions for Microsoft .NET. Telerik was founded in 2002 by a few friends. Now Telerik has a team of more than 750 professionals spread around the globe in 11 offices.

I feel like this may be an inappropriate use of a tag.  For one, it reads a bit like an ad for the company.  For another, I'm not sure it's really all that useful.  See for example the [Microsoft tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/microsoft/info), which warns users who attempt to add it to a question as follows:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! This tag is too general to be useful. Use tags more relevant to the software or device you're targeting.

So I guess I have a specific question and a general question.  First, is Telerik tag inappropriate?  And second, are vendor tags in general inappropriate?

As I see it, if vendors have multiple products/services, then a vendor tag is too general, like the Microsoft tag.  And if a vendor has a single product/service, then the tag should reflect that product/service, not the vendor itself.  So I have a hard time seeing vendor tags as ever being appropriate.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful

Comment: gah, burned by synonyms...thanks sphanley

Comment: Such tags are the basic mechanism by which support staff of small companies like [telerik], [devexpress], [componentone], [infragistics], etc, etc find their customers on SO.  [microsoft] doesn't work because it is far too big.  Product tags don't work because there are far too few questions.